# xcode: screen rotation only for some views

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation

I have created a project, with both portrait and landscape orientation. What should I do to keep only a few screens rotatable?

Answer (score 0):

Play with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

If you have a `UITabBarController`, then you you will have problems, because either all rotate or none. Although I think there are some workarounds.